# PowerShell Copy File and Create Folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to copy file from a local server to a network location. Here is what I have but I am unable to get it to work.   Not sure if I have to do an if statement of some sort?
But I need it to create a sub folder with the current date each time it runs of a scheduled task and copy the file.

```
$Destination = "\\NetShare\Account Information\" + $((Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")) + "\"
$From = "C:\data\verified2.csv"

Copy-Item -Path $From -Destination "$Destination"`
```

Comment: You should include your error message so that we can better help you. The most likely reason is your destination path doesn't exist. Note that your destination `\NetShare\...` will default to `C:\NetShare\...` without specifying the leading path.

Comment: I am getting an error that states that copy-item cannot find the path of the destination, which goes back to me wanting to make a new folder based on the date each time it copies this file to that new folder. \\Networkshare\.... is the location it is a network shared it is copying to and the account has full permisison to.

Comment: Ok, you can see the code in your post is different than what it should be, it's missing several backslash characters in the 1st line, which is due to StackOverflow formatting. Take some time to understand how to properly format your posts so others can understand them better. The reason your code isn't working is because the destination folder doesn't exist, and `Copy-Item` will not automatically create the destination folder if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The path must already exist for `Copy-Item` to work.
But in your `$Destination` example, it looks that you are trying to create a share?
I'm taking that `Account Information`is the share? In that case...

```
$Destination = '\\Server\Account Information\' + (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
$From = 'C:\data\verified2.csv'

New-Item -Path $Destination -Type Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue # don't care if it already exists

Copy-Item -Path $From -Destination $Destination
```